# How can I create key-value pairs object where value is component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to create in React key-value pair object where value is React JSX component? I've tried:

```
type ActiveTabType = {
    [key: string]: JSX.Element;
};

export const TabsContent: ActiveTabType = (services: any) => {
    [SettingsTabNames.AnnouncementTemplates]: {(<AnnouncementTemplates services={services} />)},
    [SettingsTabNames.AnnouncementCards]: <AnnouncementCards />,
};
```

but have no idea... I have still compile errors...I have problem with syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type TabsContentProps = {
services: any,
tabName: string,
}
const tabs:any = {
  [SettingsTabNames.AnnouncementTemplates]: (services) => <AnnouncementTemplates services={services}/>,
   [SettingsTabNames.AnnouncementCards]: () => <AnnouncementCards />
}

export const TabsContent: FC<TabsContentProps> = ({services, tabName}) => {
    return tabs[tabName](services)
};
```

Comment: still have compile errors like 'AnnouncementCards' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof AnnouncementCards'?

Comment: still the same error: AnnouncementCards' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof AnnouncementCards'?

Comment: OK I will try, file extension is .ts... Hmmm but anyway thanks!

Comment: OK I had .ts, should be .tsx file extension because we have JSX elements!!!